# SparkConf not reading spark-submit arguments

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

`SparkConf` on pyspark does not read the configuration arguments passed to `spark-submit`.

My python code is something like

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("foo")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

# processing code...

sc.stop()
```

and I submit it with

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON="/opt/anaconda/bin/python" spark-submit foo.py \
--master local[4] --conf="spark.driver.memory=16g" --executor-memory 16g
```

but none of the configuration arguments are applied. That is, the application is executed with the default values of local[*] for master, 1g for driver memory and 1g for executor memory. This was confirmed by the Spark GUI.

However, the configuration arguments are followed if I use pyspark to submit the application:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON="/opt/anaconda/bin/python" pyspark --master local[4] \
--conf="spark.driver.memory=8g"
```

Notice that `--executor-memory 16g` was also changed to `--conf="spark.executor.memory=16g"` because the former doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the order of the arguments matter. The last argument should be the name of the python script. So, the call should be

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON="/opt/anaconda/bin/python" spark-submit \
    --master local[4] --conf="spark.driver.memory=16g" --executor-memory 16g foo.py
```

or, following @glennie-helles-sindholt's advise,

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON="/opt/anaconda/bin/python" spark-submit \
    --master local[4] --driver-memory 16g --executor-memory 16g foo.py
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to remove the `=` sign from `--conf=`. Your `spark-submit` script should be

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON="/opt/anaconda/bin/python" spark-submit foo.py \
--master local[4] --conf spark.driver.memory=16g --executor-memory 16g
```

Note that spark-submit also supports setting driver memory with the flag `--driver-memory 16G`

Comment: That makes no sense to me. Can you paste in the command exactly as you have tried?

Comment: I have copied almost exactly the command you suggested except for the filename.